# Weird error - Data store system Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making an rpg type game in Discord.py Rewrite and when the bot is ready, i run this code and I get the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global userdata
    try:
        with open('userdata.json') as f:
            userdata = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load userdata.json")
        userdata = {}
```

Comment: From the error message it seems that there is something wrong with your json file. Can you post what you have in your userdata.json?

Comment: write {} in your JSON file and save and run the code

Comment: You shouldn't use JSON files for storage. They can corrupt easily. I recommend sqlite or mysql or my personal favorite pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see will be thrown when reading in incorrect files.
Thus the problem is most likely the fact that you dont have content in your JSON file, or have created an incorrect JSON file.

To solve this problem you need to put correct json in the file you want to load.
As @Poojan said you can do the following (to stop it throwing errors):

```
{
}
```

In order to test if your json file is correct, I recommend using this site: [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Write **{}** in your JSON file and save and run the code